# Detect if a 32bit process is running in a 64bit environment under Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I am distributing a 32bit build of a piece of software.  I want to detect at runtime whether the userland it's running under is 64bit, and capable of running 64bit executable binaries (ELF 64-bit x86-64).

This isn't the same problem as detecting at compile-time whether an architecture is 32bit or 64bit.

I would ideally like to do this in the most portable way possible, so would prefer to avoid doing things like `file $(which init) | grep x86-64` which depend on

I don't think reading cpuid is a solution either - it's possible to have a 32bit OS running on a 64bit CPU.

Detecting a 64bit cpu running in long mode doesn't seem to be a solution either, nor does detecting whether the kernel itself is 64bit, as there is the possibility that the OS is a 32bit userland with a 64bit kernel (as is possible with [some Debian configurations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134393/53118)).

I'm not primarily interested in detecting bitness other than 32 & 64.

One possible robust solution I can think of is to actually include and attempt to call a 64bit ELF binary and see if it runs or not, but this doesn't feel like a very efficient way to do it.  Is there a linux function or something in the stl or boost that could help me find out reliably?

Ironically, for once the equivalent problem is [very easy to solve under Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Why? The `file $(which init) | grep x86-64` idea may not be that insane. Of course you'll have problems on ARM64 with that, but who has ARM64 running right now?

Comment: @MSalters On my system init is in `/sbin/init` and `/sbin` is not in `$PATH` except when you are root.

Comment: @MSalters the ```file $(which init)``` idea depends on there being an init available in the path, and this being representative of the system's capability.  For an unprivileged user this may not be the case.
@mafso: yeah, the uname solution tells you what the kernel is, but it may be a problem in the case of a 32bit userland with a 64bit kernel as mentioned in the qusetion.

Comment: You could use `uname`...

Comment: @Gophyr: which tells you about the kernel, but does not address the case where a 64bit kernel is running with a 32bit userland, as mentioned in the question, or the case where a 64bit userland is running with a 32bit kernel.

Comment: @Riot: you can specify different options, for instance `uname -a` will give you all the information, including the phrase `x86_64` if you are on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @Gophyr that is not correct.  The uname syscall returns information about the kernel only.  See this question for an example of a setup reporting x86_64 from uname and actually running a 32bit userland: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134391

Comment: @Riot I'm talking about the bash command.

Comment: @Gophyr And what do you think the bash command is, aside from a wrapper around the uname linux function?  See ```man 2 uname```: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html  In bash, ```uname -a``` just dumps this entire struct.  The bit we're interested in is ```uname -m``` specifically, which just returns the uname utsname::machine[] value.  But it still only knows about the kernel.  See Brian's accepted answer below for a solution that actually takes the userland into consideration.

Comment: @Riot Try `uname -i`

Comment: @Gophyr ```uname -i``` returns "unknown" on every single machine I've run it on; looking at the source, it just queries the SI_PLATFORM compile-time define and if it's present, uses it with the sysinfo function.  See http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/uname.c and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html

Unfortunately it seems that this is rarely available; do you have SI_PLATFORM defined in your build environment?  If so, what does ```sysinfo(SI_PLATFORM, mybuffer, mybuffersize)``` give you?

Comment: @Riot It works on every Ubuntu and Debian system I have used.  Some systems support the `arch` command, you could try that.

Comment: @Gophyr the arch command is functionally identical to uname -m, which as i stated above just gets the "machine" field from the uname kernel struct; this is not relevant, as it answers about the kernel, not the userland.  What do you mean by "it works"?  What does ```uname -i``` return on your ubuntu and debian systems, and what does ```sysinfo(SI_PLATFORM, mybuffer, mybuffersize)``` give?  Because it's "unknown" on all nine debian machines I have here, and the same everywhere except on some vintage Sun boxen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test for the presence of `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Theoretically this doesn't always work because it's possible for a Linux system to put the dynamic linker somewhere else, but this particular path is by far the most common, plus the path to the dynamic linker is hardcoded into ELF binaries, so this works at least as well as actually bundling a 64-bit library with your software (provided there's a matching libc, anyway).

Comment: That's true!  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is indeed hardcoded into the 64bit ELFs, I had not realised that.  I think combining this with obtaining uname info from the kernel to avoid any risk of false positives is going to be the most robust solution for me.